# Why does my activity seemingly crash after being recreated but not on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

My first app crashed on me when trying to create a fragment (single child of activity). It was a NullPointerException on a custom 'ListViewAdapter', stored as a member variable. Through testing I believe that I handle starting and stopping of my fragment properly but I suspect I am not handling `onDestroy` and fragment recreation properly because it happened after I left the app open for a while and did other stuff.

However, my app handles orientation change, [which I thought included full recreation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html). So, my main questions are:

1. If orientation change recreates an activity, does it not also recreate its child fragment?
2. If so, why don't I get a NullPointerException when changing orientation, given that I don't perform any custom handling of my adapter through `onSavedInstanceState`?
3. How can I induce the behavior that caused a crash for testing purposes?

Here is the code that crashed:

```
// in my fragment's onCreateView()
       if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            myListViewAdapter.clear();  //this throws NullPointerException
        } else {
            courseId = ((Activity_Course) this.getActivity()).courseId;
        }
```

In this instance I can probably skip clearing the adapter if it is null, but I'd like to better understand how these things should be handled. Thanks!

Comment: Where and how you initialise your `myListViewAdapter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect I am not handling onDestroy and fragment recreation properly because it happened after I left the app open for a while and did other stuff

If I had to guess, your process was terminated while it was in the background. Whatever path you used to return to your app (e.g., recent-tasks list) did not involve re-initializing this data member.

> If orientation change recreates an activity, does it not also recreate its child fragment?

It will re-create the fragment, unless the fragment is retained (`setRetainInstance(true)`). In that case, the existing fragment is detached from the old activity and attached to the new activity.

> If so, why don't I get a NullPointerException when changing orientation, given that I don't perform any custom handling of my adapter through onSavedInstanceState?

I cannot answer that, given the information you have supplied so far.

> How can I induce the behavior that caused a crash for testing purposes?

If my guess is correct, and this was caused because your process was terminated, you can manually terminate your process via DDMS.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to troubleshoot and fix this for multiple activities by terminating from DDMS. I added key member variables to `onSaveInstanceState` and I now handle a null ListViewAdapter. Still, I wish I understood why this `Destroy/Create` experience is different than the `Destroy/Create` which I thought happened during orientation change.

Comment: @NSouth: An orientation change does not terminate your process. Terminating your process, therefore, has different effects on things like static data members than does an orientation change.

Comment: Hmm I thought that `onDestroy` was the last step in an activity's lifecycle and orientation change calls `onDestroy'. Do you have any more info on how exactly these destructions are different?

Comment: @NSouth: "I thought that onDestroy was the last step in an activity's lifecycle" -- it is. "and orientation change calls `onDestroy'" -- it does. So will some process terminations. However, an orientation change does not terminate your process, and there are things, like static data members, that go away when your process does.

Comment: So both cases destroy the activity, but orientation change destroys it in such a way that static members are handled differently than if the entire process is killed. Correct? Thanks for helping me understand this!

Comment: @NSouth: "but orientation change destroys it in such a way that static members are handled differently than if the entire process is killed. Correct?" -- yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't initialized the arraylist or list that you were suppose to use for the listview. also don't forget setAdapter and NotifyDataSetChanged.